# Global Admin can't change sharing on Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, error

We have 3 Global Admins and 2 of the 3 have this problem and the other does not.

When going into Sharepoint online and trying to change the Sharing permissions for the group, we get the following error:

**URL:** https://sitename-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/AdminHome.aspx#/sharing

**Error on loading page:** UntaggedErrorWithStatusCode403: No inner error provided

**Error when attempting to change permissions with the slider:** UntaggedErrorWithStatusCode403: No inner error provided
Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.

I can't see any other issues like in my google searches.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do all 3 have SharePoint license assigned?

Comment: Yep, I have SharePoint licensed for my user. Chris.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the difference between the three global admins.

To change external sharing settings, you need to be a global or SharePoint admin and have SharePoint license. In my test, if a global admin doesn't have SharePoint license, he will be unable to access SharePoint admin center.

Comment: I can access SharePoint admin centre fine.

Comment: I have 3 Global Admins, all 3 have sharepoint licenses, all 3 can access Sharepoint admin pages, only 1 can access and change global sharing within Sharepoint online.

Comment: When testing the 3 accounts, did you use a same machines or different machines? Please try to clear your browser cache and test again. If this issue still exits, you can try to change the 2 problematic global admins roles to others and revert it again, then test again.

Comment: I needed to download the Sharepoint Online Management Shell (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588)
Connect using: connect-sposervice
Enter my site URL https://mysite-admin.sharepoint.com

Run: Set-SPOUser -Site https://mysite-admin.sharepoint.com -LoginName myuser@mydomain.com -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $true

This resolved it.